# Jenkins "Warnings Next Generation Plugin" can't parse Pytest's JUnit xml report

Tags: jenkins, pytest

I'm having some issues with the xml report produced by Pytest 5.4.1.

The report is produced using the following command

```
python -m pytest --junitxml report.xml
```

When Jenkins tries to parse it via the **Warnings Next Generation Plugin 8.1.0** I get the following exception:

`[JUnit] [-ERROR-] java.lang.RuntimeException: "type" not found in "<testcase classname="...`

It looks like each **testcase** element in the report is missing a **type** attribute.

Is there a simple way I could add the type attribute into every testcase element? I know I could use the **record_xml_attribute** fixture but how do I apply it to every test in my project ?

```py
def test_function(record_xml_attribute):
    record_xml_attribute("type", "I'll figure what goes here later")
    assert True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an auto-used fixture (provided you always need the same type):

```python
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def add_type(record_xml_attribute):
    record_xml_attribute("type", "Whatever you figured out")
```

This will add the `type` attribute to each testcase in the report.

Note that the fixture has to be located in a scope that includes all tests that shall be adapted, e.g. in the `conftest.py` in the root directory of all your tests, if you have more than one test file.

Comment: Hm did this the trick although I had to add the fixture to the root directory inside a conftest.py file to apply it to all the tests in the project.

Comment: Yes, right, I didn't mention this - it has to be visible to all tests, of course. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: The xml report is now parsed without exceptions. The problem is JUnit reports says 0 warnings although there should be. Looks like the schema used by pytest is not compatible with the Jenkins warnings plugin?

Comment: Just to make sure - you did configure the jenkins plugin for junit, right? (and run pytest with `--junitxml`)

Comment: On Jenkins side I'm using https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/ which supports parsing JUnit reports (one of many). My initial idea was to use this to consolidate all of the static analysis/ unit test reports in one, which is the point of this plugin

Comment: Yes, I got this, just wanted to make sure you configured both sides for JUnit. I have used the plugin, but not with pytest.